# Lookup Values for VendorInvoiceReviewStatus For Vendor Invoice

Tags: lookup-tables, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-operations

I've just joined an organisation that is using Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations as a SSRS report developer.

Data from the Dynamics 365 system are pushed by way of bespoke data entities to an Azure SQL Database. It's from the Azure SQL db that I am querying the tables to produce reports.

One of the reports I am writing is referencing the [VendorInvoiceReviewStatus] column and this holds integer values.  There isn't a lookup table that I can join to select related Text values ti display in the report.

The contractor the was brought in to deploy this system has long gone and the users left behind know how to use the system from a functional perspective.  I was told the contractor was able to delve into the "code" to look up these values and create a bespoke lookup table.  Now that's he's no longer around I am stuck.

I am hoping these values are standard and someone can tell what they are or point me to an article that tells me.

Answer (score 2):

In Dynamics 365 applications:- May it be Dynamics crm or Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations, Option Sets are combination of Integer Value and Text (Label).
You wish to get Label of this particular Field.
What you could do is Go to Dynamics 365 Finance and Operations application, Go to particular Entity where this field is part of and you could see Text for Integer Value.
Please find below Option Set from Dynamics CRM. This will give you Idea where to look for.

[image]

[image]
[image]